# return array of system::string

Tags: arrays, winforms, c++-cli

Trying to return an array of system::string

I'm new to c++ and I'm trying to return an array of string but seems a little hard.

```
public: array<String^>^  getData() {
        
        return {tb1->Text,tb2->Text,tb3->Text,tb4->Text,tb5->Text,tb6->Text };

    }
```

the tb's are textboxes (I'm working on a windows form). Also how is this string different from regular ones?
Is it possible to use the regular string instead? Or convert them regular string and vice-versa.

Comment: the code is not c++

Comment: What is this `array` exactly? Is it `std::array` or some `.net` `array` (so it is managed)? Note C++-CLI is kind of bridge between regular C++ and managed code (`.net`-y). If you do not build special bridge between those to there is not point to use it. Some time ago I was using that to expose C++ library (which was mutiplatform) to C#.

Comment: If you're new to C++ then why do you start with c++/cli? I advise you to first learn C++ and .Net seperately. They have VERY DIFFERENT memory managment (and object lifetime)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It is managed C++ (or at least an attempt to do that)

Comment: assuming array is managed in this declaration of function code should look like this:  `return gcnew array<String^>{ tb1->Text, tb2->Text, tb3->Text, tb4->Text, tb5->Text, tb6->Text };`. Assuming this is `std::array` then declaration of function is wrong: `std::array<String^> getData()`.

Answer (score 2):

OK, you have several questions in there.

The main question: How to return the array of strings: You're on the right track, but I think the compiler can't quite deduce that it needs to do `gcnew cli::array<String^>`. So you do that explicitly.

```
return gcnew cli::array<String^>{ tb1->Text, tb2->Text, tb3->Text, tb4->Text, tb5->Text, tb6->Text };
```

Notes:

- I like to use `cli::array` instead of `array` to make it obvious that we're not dealing with an unmanaged `std::array`, but you don't have to do that if you don't want.

Side questions: Also how is this string different from regular ones? Is it possible to use the regular string instead? Or convert them regular string and vice-versa.

- How is this string different: These are managed strings. Or to put it another way, these are C# strings, and "regular" strings are C++ strings. The full name is `System::String`, instead of `std::string`. In order to deal with these managed strings, you're going to need your code to be managed: That means you'll be writing managed classes, and calling the .Net library, not the C++ Library, to operate on these strings.
- Possible to use regular: For the WinForms and TextBoxes, no. Those are .Net components, so they use managed strings. Also, my recommendation for C++/CLI is to write in a C# style, so that means using the various managed objects, including managed strings.
- Convert them: Yes, you can convert to `std::string`. (Managed strings are innately wide character strings, so you probably want to convert to `std::wstring` instead.) To convert, use the marshal_as method. `#include <marshal_cppstd.h>`, then `std::wstring cppString = marshal_as<std::wstring>(managedString);` and `System::String^ managedString = marshal_as<System::String>(cppString);`.

Finally a general disclaimer about C++/CLI:

This language is intended to allow C# and C++ code to coexist and call each other easily. It has all the complexities of C++, all the complexities of C#, and additional complexities all its own. It was never intended to be a primary development language. My recommendation would be to switch to another language.

For writing a WinForms app, my recommendation would be to switch from C++/CLI to C#. That's the language that WinForms was intended for, and you'll have a much easier time finding resources to help you.

If you really do want to write a GUI in C++, my recommendation would be to drop C++/CLI, use plain unmanaged C++, and use [Microsoft Foundation Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/mfc-desktop-applications) (MFC). Again, there's tons of resources for how to do things in plain C++ with MFC.

(If you're not sure which switch you want to do, I recommend C# with WinForms. Programming in C# is generally easier, with you having to do fewer things manually.)